# Binary search of an integer array

Tags: python, beginner, reinventing-the-wheel, binary-search

I'm a beginner. This is my implementation of binary search algorithm in Python. Please review my code and give your valuable inputs for further improvements on overall coding style, rare cases etc.

```
def binary_search(arr,value):
    left = 0
    right = len(arr) - 1
    while(left <= right):
        mid = (left + right) // 2
        print(mid)
        if arr[mid] is value:
            return mid
        elif value < arr[mid]:
            right = mid - 1
        elif value > arr[mid]:
            left = mid + 1

    return -1

def print_binary_search(arr,value):
    pos = binary_search(arr,value)
    if pos is -1:
        print("Element not found")
    else:
        print("Element found in the positon " +str(pos))



def test1():
    arr = [2,5,8,9,11,15,17,19,22,26,29,33,56]
    value = 56
    print_binary_search(arr,value)

def test2():
    arr = [2,5,8,9,11,15,17,19,22,26,29,33,56]
    value = 59
    print_binary_search(arr,value)


test1()
test2()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### 1. Review

1. There's no docstring. It's a good idea to write a specification for each function you write — without knowing what a function is supposed to do, it's impossible to check that the implementation is correct. In this case I'd write:

   ```
   def binary_search(arr, value):
       """Given a sorted sequence arr, return an index i such that arr[i] == value.
       Return -1 if no element in arr is equal to value.

       """
   ```

   (Note that this doesn't say what happens if there are more than one index `i` meeting the condition — you might want to say "return the *leftmost* index" or "return the *rightmost* index" if you care about this.)
2. The line `print(mid)` seems to have been accidentally left over after a debugging session.
3. The function `binary_search` has a chain of tests `if condition1: ... elif condition2: ...` with no `else:` on the end. Whenever you spot this pattern, you should always be suspicious, because what if none of the conditions is true? In this case I'd write:

   ```
   if arr[mid] == value:
       return mid
   elif value < arr[mid]:
       right = mid - 1
   else: # value > arr[mid]
       left = mid + 1
   ```

   This makes it clear that exactly one of the three cases has to happen.
4. The code evaluates `arr[mid]` up to three times. It would slightly faster to evaluate it just once and remember the result in a local variable:

   ```
   mid_value = arr[mid]
   if mid_value == value:
       return mid
   elif value < mid_value:
       right = mid - 1
   else: # value > mid_value
       left = mid + 1
   ```
5. In programming, it's often more convenient to represent a range of numbers in "half-open" form — that is, inclusive on the lower end and exclusive on the higher end. This reduces the number of operations and helps avoid off-by-one errors.

   In this case, there is a subtraction in two places:

   ```
   right = len(arr) - 1
   # ...
   right = mid - 1
   ```

   By keeping the range from left to right in half-open form, both of these subtractions could be avoided. The condition on the `while` loop would then become:

   ```
   while left < right:
   ```
6. Each time around the `while` loop, the code tests (up to) *four* conditions:

   ```
   while left <= right:
   if arr[mid] == value:
   elif value < arr[mid]:
   elif value > arr[mid]:
   ```

   I showed above how to reduce this to three. But it is possible to reduce it to *two* by omitting the test `arr[mid] == value`, like this:

   ```
   left = 0
   right = len(arr)
   while left < right:
       mid = (left + right) // 2
       if arr[mid] < value:
           left = mid + 1
       else: # arr[mid] >= value
           right = mid
   ```

   It's a good idea to play with some examples to see how this works — the idea is that when `arr[mid] == value` you set `right = mid` and then subsequent loops just increase `left` until `left == right` and then the `while` loop exits.
7. The code handles the exceptional situation (the value is not found in the sequence) by returned an exceptional value (−1). This is an error-prone design because it would be very easy for the caller to forget to check for the exceptional value. It would be easy to write:

   ```
   i = binary_search(my_array, my_value)
   found_value = my_array[i]
   ```

   which would go wrong when `i` is `-1`. It's better to handle an exceptional situation by raise an exception.

#### 2. Revised code

```
def binary_search(arr, value):
    """Given a sorted sequence arr, return the leftmost i such that
    arr[i] == value. Raise ValueError if no element in arr is equal
    to value.

    """
    left = 0
    right = len(arr)
    while left < right:
        mid = (left + right) // 2
        if value > arr[mid]:
            left = mid + 1
        else:
            right = mid
    if left != len(arr) and arr[left] == value:
        return left
    else:
        raise ValueError("{!r} is not in sequence".format(value))
```

#### 3. Using bisect module

Python has a built-in [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html) module for searching sorted sequences. If you look at the section "[Searching Sorted Lists](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#searching-sorted-lists)" you'll see that your function can be implemented like this:

```
from bisect import bisect_left

def index(a, x):
    'Locate the leftmost value exactly equal to x'
    i = bisect_left(a, x)
    if i != len(a) and a[i] == x:
        return i
    raise ValueError
```

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed review. I will try to follow your suggestions in my future programs.

Answer (score 5):

1. `if arr[mid] is value:`

   You don't want to compare two integers with `is`, which compares identity. Use `==` instead. `is` will break your code when using large or small numbers (\$<-5\$, \$>256\$).

   For example, using `is` with this "test" function:

   ```
   def test1():
       arr = list(range(257, 270))
       value = 260
       print_binary_search(arr, value)
   ```

   Results with an infinite loop.

   Using `==` works as expected and returns `3`.

   The reason is that Python uses integer caching for the range \$[-5, 256]\$.

And some [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) nitpicking:

2. `while(left <= right):`

   The parenthesis around the condition are useless in this case, you should prefer a whitespace:

   ```
   while left <= right:
   ```
3. You are missing some whitespaces after commas in function definition, function calls, list literals and around operators.

   For example, your code should look like this (relevant lines only):

   ```
   def print_binary_search(arr, value):

   #######

   pos = binary_search(arr, value)

   #######

   arr = [2, 5, 8, 9, 11, 15, 17, 19, 22, 26, 29, 33, 56]

   #######

   print("Element found in the position " + str(pos))
   ```

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions. I have checked my code in python 3 compiler and I'm not getting an infinite loop for using "is". Anyway, using "==" is more clear.

Comment: I never knew about PEP8. Thanks for sharing it

Comment: @Arun Note that it will only happen if using numbers outside the range [-5, 256].

Answer (score -2):

and according to a recent hot discussion on SO.

you should use `mid = left + (right-left)/2` instead of `mid = (left+right)/2` to avoid possible overflows

Comment: This is not necessary in Python which has built-in bignums. Also, it's important to use `//` in Python to get the floor division operator.